# Equation of perpendicular line to tangent lines

Tags: graphing-functions, tangent-line

I'm completely stuck on a question about equation of perpendicular lines to tangent lines.
I figured out my tangent lines equations, I know graphically what I should get for my perpendicular lines (x=-1 and x=1) but how can I prove that mathematically?

Thanks a lot for your help

[image: prompt]

Comment: Try to post what you did from next time.

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal tangent line must have a slope of $0$. So that will be a line in the form of $y = 0*x + c = c$.

So at which points on the curve $y=x^3 -3x + 1$ is the slope $0$?

Well the derivative is the formula for the slope.  (Assuming the function *is* differentiable).

So we must solve for $y' =3x^2 - 3 = 0$.  Let $x_0, x_1$ be the two solutions to that.

So the equations of your tangent lines will be:  $y= (x_0^3 -3x + 1)$ and $y = (x_1^3 -3x_1 + 1)$

2)  A line perpendicular would be completely vertical.  So they will have the form $x = c$ for some constant.  In this case those lines are at $x=x_0$ and $x=x_1$.  So those are you equations.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the curve is given by $y=x^3-3x+1$ Therefore the slope of the tangent is given by:
$$\dot{y}=3x^2-3$$
Where the tangent is horizontal is when the slope of the tangent is zero $\implies \dot{y}=0$ or, $x=\pm 1$. The points where this happens are given by $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,3)$.

Now the when the tangent is horizontal the normal will be vertical $\implies$ it will have a form $x=c$. At $(1,-1)$ it is $x=1$ and at $(-1,3)$ it is $x=-1$.
$$$$